# Nintendo 64 game will not boot!

Tags: nintendo-64

I recently purchased Conkers Bad Fur Day for Nintendo 64 and it came today. I plugged it into my Nintendo 64 and I got nothing but a black screen. I cleaned the contacts on the board with isopropyl and Q-tips but still refused to boot.[image: Pin condition]

I then tested some of my other games to make sure it wasn't the ram that had gone, or that the pins inside were dirty. All my other games work fine.

I then opened it up completely to have a look at the internals and one of the screw holes for the motherboard had been snapped off (Check images for look-see). Upon research it was only used for grounding the motherboard so it didn't matter that much as the other hole was fine[image: Snaped piece of mother board and also Boot chip name and info]

I have no other ideas as to why the game will not work/boot on my console.

P.S If there is anything anyone wants to see on the board, feel free to ask if it helps me finally get to play this amazing game!!!!

**EDIT:** May have found the problem. Two points on the board were cold solder points and also had lifted pads. Going to try re-solder them and see what happens

Comment: If your resoldering works, then please post that as an answer and not as an edit. Keeping answers and questions separate is a good thing :)

Comment: YES THE SOLDERING WORKED!!!!!!! Used a multi-meter to check which connections were broken and fixed them

Comment: Congrats on fixing it! Go ahead and post an answer (not a comment with what you just did (plus a picture of the result). I'll gladly upvote.

Answer (score 8):

Checked solder points on back, two were broken. Re-flowed them and had to jump them to the next point on the trace. Game now works. Will upload photos when I get home

The two broken points soldered back to the corresponding pin.
[image]